# Iterate through object keys and values and return a new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I've got an array of objects, which share common property names, but have different values. For example, they go like this:

```
let data = [
    {
      value1: "11:00",
      value2: 0.737462,
      value3: 1.345341,
      value4: 0.684655
    },
    {
      value1: "12:00",
      value2: 0.894368,
      value3: 1.55891,
      value4: 0.784655
    },
    {
      value1: "13:00",
      value2: 1.140516,
      value3: 1.938695,
      value4: 0.454655
    }
]
```

From these objects, I need to form a new array of objects, similar to this:

```
let datasets = [
    {
        label: "value1",
        data: ["11:00", "12:00", "13:00"]
    },
    {
        label: "value2",
        data: [0.737462,0.894368,1.140516,]
    }
    // and so on
]
```

So that each object in my dataset would contain the original object's property name as a value for `label` and the array of properties that correspond to that name. I've tried to do it like this:

```
let datasets = data.map((n) => {
    for (i in n) {
        return {
            label: i,
            data: data.map(obj => obj[i])
        }
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work as expected -- it returns just an array of objects with only the first property name as a label throughout them all. I guess it's because it returns as soon as it gets to the first item in the `for...in` loop, but I can't figure out a better way to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of elements in the expected array is equal to the number of keys in an array element so map over that, then run another simple map to generate the data array.

```
var out = Object.keys(data[0]).map(function(key) {
  return {
    label: key,
    data: data.map(function(obj) {
      return obj[key];
    })
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `reduce()` and ES6 `Map`.

```js
let data = [{"value1":"11:00","value2":0.737462,"value3":1.345341,"value4":0.684655},{"value1":"12:00","value2":0.894368,"value3":1.55891,"value4":0.784655},{"value1":"13:00","value2":1.140516,"value3":1.938695,"value4":0.454655}]

var result = [...data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  return Object.keys(e).forEach(k => {
    if(!r.has(k)) r.set(k, {label: k, data: [e[k]]})
    else r.get(k).data.push(e[k])
  }), r
}, new Map).values()]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Note: it will work in case like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2593/

Answer (score 0):

```
const datasets = data.reduce((acc, a) => {
    return acc.map(set => Object.assign({}, set, { data: set.data.concat(a[set.label])}));
}, Object.keys(data[0]).map(k => ({label: k, data: []})));
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mc9m8vdq/).